# Scripting Bridge and filtering SBElementArrays using NSPredicate and FourCharCodes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes, scripting-bridge

I'm experimenting with Scripting Bridge for the the first time, but have run into an issue with filtering a `SBElementArray` according to a NSPredicate containing a FourCharCode enum constant as a criterion.

I wrote a trivial program to identify the "library" source in a user's iTunes library, by using `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` to filter the `SBElementArray` of all iTunes sources. I was expecting to get back an `SBElementArray` that, when evaluated, would produce an array of one element, namely the library source. Instead, when I call `-get` on the returned `SBElementArray`, I get back an empty array.

Perplexingly, if change the order and instead call `-get` on the `SBElementArray` of all sources to get a concrete `NSArray`, and call `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` on this array with the same predicate as before, I do get the desired result. I don't believe this is supposed to be necessary however, and I've had success filtering a `SBElementArray` using other NSPredicates (e.g. `@"name=='Library'"` works fine).

The code snippet is below. `iTunesESrcLibrary` is a FourCharCode constant defined in the header file generated by Scripting Bridge. (`iTunesESrcLibrary = 'kLib'`). I'm running 10.6.5.

```
iTunesApplication* iTunes = [[SBApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];   

NSPredicate* libraryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %u", iTunesESrcLibrary];

SBElementArray* allSources_Attempt1 = [iTunes sources];
SBElementArray* allLibrarySources_Attempt1 = (SBElementArray*)[allSources_Attempt1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:libraryPredicate];

NSLog(@"Attempt 1: %@", allLibrarySources_Attempt1);
NSLog(@"Attempt 1 (evaluated): %@", [allLibrarySources_Attempt1 get]);


NSArray* allSources_Attempt2 = [[iTunes sources] get];
NSArray* allLibrarySources_Attempt2 = [allSources_Attempt2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:libraryPredicate];

NSLog(@"Attempt 2: %@", allLibrarySources_Attempt2);
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Attempt 1: <SBElementArray @0x3091010: ITunesSource whose 'cmpd'{ 'relo':'=   ', 'obj1':'obj '{ 'want':'prop', 'from':'exmn'($$), 'form':'prop', 'seld':'pKnd' }, 'obj2':1800169826 } of application "iTunes" (88827)>
Attempt 1 (evaluated): (
)
Attempt 2: (
"<ITunesSource @0x3091f10: ITunesSource id 65 of application \"iTunes\" (88827)>"
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. It seems you can't simply use a FourCharCode's integer value directly in a `NSPredicate` that you intend to use to filter an `SBElementArray`.

By chance, I found that instead of:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %u", iTunesESrcLibrary]
```

you need to use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kind == %@", [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithTypeCode: iTunesESrcLibrary]]
```

Using this second form, I can filter the `SBElementArray` sources list as expected. However, this new predicate can't be used to filter the `NSArray`, even though this array is just the evaluated form of the `SBElementArray`! Here, you have to switch back to the `%u` version.

Rant:
Frankly this sucks, and it seems the sort of thing Scripting Bridge should deal with so I don't have to; I shouldn't have to know what an `NSAppleEventDescriptor` is. And while it's reasonable that not all predicates that work with `NSArray` should work with `SBElementArray`, the converse should not be the case and it's unnecessarily confusing that it is.

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm digging into Scripting Bridge as well for a bunch of internal production work and I've had to come up with a couple wrapper classes to make SB easier to use. The work is worth it just for the Cocoa integration alone, but there are a lot of hoops to jump through to get started.